# What is the difference between declarations and entryComponents

Tags: angular

I have this in my app.module.ts:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EliteApi } from '../shared/shared';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { MyTeams, Tournaments, TeamDetails, Teams, TeamHome, Standings } from '../pages/pages';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        MyTeams,
        TeamDetails,
        Tournaments,
        Teams,
        TeamHome,
        Standings
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
        HttpModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        MyTeams,
        TeamDetails,
        Tournaments,
        Teams,
        TeamHome,
        Standings
    ],
    providers: [
        HttpModule,
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },        
        EliteApi
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

At the moment my `declarations` and `entryComponents` both are exactly the same. They contain all of the page/components that I built for my app. If I remove any entry from any of the properties I get error in angular2.

My question is if they are always the same then what is the need for these properties? I think I am definitely missing some point here. When would entryComponents and declaractions be different from one another?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The `entryComponents` array is used to define *only* components that are not found in html and created dynamically with `ComponentFactoryResolver`. Angular needs this hint to find them and compile. All other components should just be listed in the declarations array.

[Here's the documentation on angular site](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-is-an-entry-component)

Comment: Why and when to use `EntryComponents` property in ngModule ? still not clear , would be better if you add some more explanation

Comment: @PardeepJain : I also stumbled upon the same issue. I have added one use case . I hope this will help others as well

Comment: Documentation link address has been changed I guess https://angular.io/guide/entry-components

Comment: Could it be that a component be placed in the `entryComponents` block, not because it is not also placed in the `declarations` block, but simply because we want it to be precompiled ?

Comment: entryComponents are also used for custom components (Web Components). I saw it in the docs!

Answer (score 35):

Adding to what @Julia has answered to this question. I would like to add use case of **Modal**.

---

Lets say, you have a component called as `ModalComponent`. To make it more reusable, you would like to pass a component name and expect that component to be rendered inside the `ModalComponent`*.

Sample `module.ts` would be something like:

```
import:[ModalModule],  // As a best practice, we can create Modal as a separate Feature
entryComponent : [TheCompYouWantToRenderInsideModalComponent]
```

We would pass `TheCompYouWantToRenderInsideModalComponent` as `entryComponent` because this component will not be present while writing the website code (**i.e there would not be selector of `TheCompYouWantToRenderInsideModalComponent` in any `HTML` file**). We will pass this `component` to Modal and then it'll be rendered **dynamically** as and  when the modal is opened. Something like below:

```
onSomeButtonClickToOpenModal(){
     this.modalService.openModal(TheCompYouWantToRenderInsideModalComponent);
}
```

---

<sub>*In the `ModalModule`, we would create service to use `ComponentFactoryResolver` and take `TheCompYouWantToRenderInsideModalComponent` as argument. Later, we can call a function (call it `openModal(componentType: ComponentType)`) which will Open & render using `ComponentFactoryResolver`</sub>

---

***Side Note:*** The `entryComponent` will also play an important part in Angular V6 `elements` feature for the same purpose.

***Update: Angular 9***

With `Angular 9` being released, we no more need to have `entryComponent` , Thanks to **Ivy compiler**

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Thank you!

Comment: @Nicwenda : Thanks :) I struggled as well and felt this answer worth sharing

Comment: Awesome explanation

Answer (score 5):

**In short:**

The "real" reason behind the existence of `entryComponents` is tree-shaking, while `declarations` exists mainly for module encapsulation. So they aren't even comparable. If tree-shaking wasn't our concern, we would be good with declarations as a single source for both.

**Longer answer**

All the `components` that you created in your `module` don't go to final bundle. Rather, only the components which were declared in `template` using `selectors` OR the `components` that were added to `entryComponents` array (by you or the framework).

You would want to add the component when you creating the component dynamically like using `ComponentFactoryResolver` as stated by accepted answer. Or framework can add the component when you declare them in Route array or during other imperative creation.

From official docs:

> In fact, many libraries declare and export components you'll never
>   use. For example, a material design library will export all components
>   because it doesn’t know which ones you will use. However, it is
>   unlikely that you will use them all. For the ones you don't reference,
>   the tree shaker drops these components from the final code package.
>
> **If a component isn't an entry component and isn't found in a template,
>   the tree shaker will throw it away**. So, it's best to add only the
>   components that are truly entry components to help keep your app as
>   trim as possible.

Answer (score 4):

for **Angular 9** or Angular 8 with **Ivy** explicitly enabled

Entry Components With Ivy is not required anymore and and now deprecated

Comment: Yes, Angular 9 has omitted it.

Answer (score 1):

**For this you need to understand how angular actually
works behind the scenes when it comes to creating components.**

Any component as well as directives and pipes you plan on working with, you need to add them to your `declarations` array in `@NgModule` of `app.module.ts`(while working with multiple `modules`, we import the feature module in our `app.module.ts` `imports` array, and that `feature module` has all the components in its `declarations` array).

The above mentioned step is important for angular to understand what's a component or which components and directives you have in your app because, it **does not automatically scan** all your files.
You'd need to tell it which components exist, after creating a new component.

Still this alone only makes angular aware of it so that it is able to create such a component when it finds it in one of two places--

1. The first place would be in your templates if in your templates angular finds a `selector` of a component-->
   then it basically looks into the `declarations` array for that particular component-->
   finds that there and then is able to create that component.
2. The other place where angular will look for this component is in your `routs`in your `rout config`,-->
   when you point at a component there angular will also check that in the `declarations` array and-->
   if it finds that there it is able to create such a component and load it.

Now one place that **does not** work by default is when you want to create a component manually in code. Like when you want to create a `dynamic component`with `component factory` like an `alert component` maybe which only shows up when there is any error and **you neither mention the `selector` of it in any `template` nor in the `rout config`**.

And now, here angular does not automatically reach out to the declarations array.
It simply doesn't do that.
You can complain about that.
Still it's the case.

You instead deliberately need to inform angular that in this case the alert component will need to be created at some place and that angular basically should be prepared for this.

Generally angular will prepare itself for this creation when it finds a component in the `template` or in a `rout config`.But in our case as we haven't done either of the two things as mentioned above, angular won't do prepare itself.

Now to tell angular to be prepared for the creation of that component you need to add a special property to the object you pass to `Ngmodule` besides `declarations` `import` and so on.
That property is `entry components`, it is an array of component types, but only those components that will eventually be created without `routs` or `selectors`.

**But with the launch of Angular 9, there were changes made behind the scenes, and it does all these work for you, you do not need to mention the `entry components` manually anymore.**

Credits--Learned these concepts from the Udemy course "Angular the Complete Guide" -by Maximilian Schwarzmüller .

Comment: Best explanation here!

Answer (score 0):

An entry component is any component that Angular loads imperatively, which means you’re not referencing it in the template, by type.
For Example :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-entry-component', // <== component select tags
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppEntryComponent {
  // <== Component Class
}
```

add this selector in the component you are using

```
<app-entry-component></app-entry-component>
```

add this component in appmodule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ComponentClassName,
    children: []
  }
]
```

finally

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    AppEntryComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: and if you also do not mention it in the routs.