# Difference between entryComponents

Tags: angular

Recently i tried to understand what's the difference between `NgModule's entryComponents` and `Component's entryComponents`.
Couldn't find any information about this on the internet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43815995/what-is-the-difference-between-declarations-and-entrycomponents?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka unrelated, re-read the question. As for the OP, I imagine that component's entryComponents are components appended dynamically inside the component itself ; whereas in the module, the entry components are for the whole module. It's just a scope question.